How can I fix "FileNotFoundError" so that I only have to type in the filename and not some absurdly long filepath everytime?
simple python in vscode and filenotfound error in terminal
I get this error everytime I try to reference a file in this way, or with the long file path.
I've tried with JSON files as well but get the same error. I followed some tutorials on YouTube and expected there to be no problems whatsoever, but I can't seem to find a durable solution. However, Copilot did provide me with a solution, but I would prefer not to rely on it everytime as I didn't really understand it, I just copy pasted it and it worked, but here it is:
# Get the current directory of the script
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Construct the absolute path to the CSV file
csv_file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "googleplaystore.csv")


From where are you executing the script?

Update:
As @Matthias commented, the filepath library would be the modern way of doing it.
from pathlib import Path
filepath = Path(__file__).parent / "your_file.txt"

Now filepath is an object representing a system path that allows you to perform multiple operations.

__file__ is the path to the currently executing python file
Path(__file__) creates the Path object
Path(__file__).parent creates the path object and gets it's parent (parent is still a Path object)
Path(__file__).parent / "your_file.txt" the slash operator creates a new Path object concatenating both parts, if any part is absolute path, the previous parts are ignored

So Path('/var/log') / '/apache2/access.log' is not '/var/log/apache2/access.log' but '/apache2/access.log' because the second part is considered an absolute path.

You should use something like this:
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = "your_file.txt"
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, filename)


Regardless if you do
cd /tmp
python /path/to/python/script.py

or
cd /path/to/python/
python script.py

script_dir should always be /path/to/python/
__file__ is the path of the current python file (main file or module).
Edit: I just saw that you answered yourself, why the question then?

but I would prefer not to rely on it everytime as I didn't really understand it

Then what you should do is try to understand it, not look for a different answer.
Edit2:
To explain:

__file__ is the path to the currently executing python file
os.path.realpath(__file__) is the canonical full path to the currently executing python file, this is to resolve any symbolic links
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) is to grab the parent directory of the currently executing python file

So if __file__ is /tmp/script/main.py you end up with /tmp/script/

The reason why I "answered" myself is because in every single tutorial I've watched they haven't mentioned whatever code you provided me with here, so I thought that surely there must be a way that you don't have to type all those extra lines of code in order to refrence a file. But I guess the tutorials sucked then, or is it because they were on windows?

No, you're using relative paths so when you execute a python script the python interpreter has the working directory you had, so when it tries to read a file open('file.txt') it looks for it in it's current directory. Which in you image seems to be VSCode, do cd VScode/Auniverse/3B_Datasett then execute the script, now you can use JUST the file name, but it will only work when execute from it´s directory.

But I appreciate your answer and straight forwardness, if this is the correct way to do it everytime then I will definetly learn it correctly from the getgo, so in a way you answered my question spot on. Thanks

Just saw your last comment. That makes a lot of sense, thanks a lot. I totally forgot about from where I was executing my script.

added an explanation to the functions used and why they're used.

os.path is a little bit outdated. I suggest using pathlib: filepath = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "your_file.txt"
